# Python: Updating Class Instances in one List-Variable based on same Class Instances from Another List-Variable

Tags: python, class

There are two list variables: listA and listB. Both lists store three instances of MyClass. The difference between listA and listB is that listB's instances have their self.attrA set to "myValue". At the end of script I am looping through listA and listB to check if their instances self.id attributes match. If they do I want to update (override) listA instance with a corresponding listB instance (so listA instances all have their self.myAttr set to "myValue". Strangely listA instances remain unchanged even after
they set to be equal: `

```
inst_A = inst_B
```

Where is the mistake?

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        super(MyClass, self).__init__()
        self.id=None
        self.attrA=None
        if 'id' in arg.keys(): 
            self.id=arg['id']
        if 'attrA' in arg.keys(): 
            self.attrA=arg['attrA']

listA=[]
for i in range(3): 
    listA.append( MyClass({'id':i}))

listB=[]
for i in range(3): 
    listB.append( MyClass({'id':i, 'attrA':'myValue'}))

for inst_A in listA:
    for inst_B in listB:
        if inst_A.id==inst_B.id:
            inst_A=inst_B

for inst_A in listA:
    print inst_A.attrA
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your for loop isn't mutating your list, it's mutating your iteration variable.

```
for inst_A in listA: # this creates a new name called inst_A which points
                     # to a value in listA
    for inst_B in listB:
        if inst_A.id == inst_B.id:
            # this assignment changes the inst_A name to now point to inst_B
            inst_A = inst_B

    # At the bottom of the loop, inst_A is recycled, so the value it was 
    # assigned to (inst_B) is forgotten
```

Try:

```
for i in range(len(listA)): 
    for inst_B in listB:
        if listA[i].id == inst_B.id:
            # almost the same as above, except here we're changing the value
            # of the i-th entry in listA
            listA[i] = inst_B
```

Comment: In fact, I don't think this is entirely correct. if you change inst_A = inst_B to inst_A.attrA=inst_B.attrA, it works fine. My idea is that you can change the value of iteration variable, but not replace it entirely.

Comment: You can't pass a list to `range`. Change it to `range(len(listA))`.

Comment: Thanks guys! Great stuff to know.